# Sort through multiple list using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have multiple list on a page. An example of a list looks like this:

```
<ul class="effects-list">
  <li data-sorte="2">creative</li>
  <li data-sorte="1">euphoric</li>
  <li data-sorte="2">uplifted</li>
  <li data-sorte="1">energetic</li>
  <li data-sorte="0">lazy</li>
  <li data-sorte="1">focused</li>
  <li data-sorte="2">happy</li>
  <li data-sorte="0">talkative</li>
  <li data-sorte="0">giggly</li>
  <li data-sorte="0">tingly</li>
  <li data-sorte="0">hungry</li>
  <li data-sorte="0">sleepy</li>
  <li data-sorte="0">aroused</li>
</ul>
```

I have a script that will remove all `data-sorte` that equals `0`. After that is done, it sorts the list from highest to lowest (again by the numbers stored in `data-sorte`). It then takes the top three options and removes the rest.

Here is the script that does this:

```
$('*[data-sorte="0"]').remove();
    $(".effects-list li").sort(sort_li_effects).appendTo('.effects-list');
function sort_li_effects(a, b){
    return ($(a).data('sorte')) < ($(b).data('sorte')) ? 1 : -1;    
}
$(".effects-list li").filter( function(k, v) {
    if( k < 3 ) {
        min = parseInt($(v).data('sorte'));
        return false;
    } else
        return min > parseInt($(v).data('sorte'));
}).remove();
```

The problem I have is it sorts all of the list based on the first list. My question is how do I modify the script so it sorts all of the list on the page correctly?

[Here is a jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lynda333/KK2bV/1/) with working code that shows the problem.

**EDIT**

To clarify a point. Lets say I have the following list:

```
<ul class="effects-list">
  <li data-sorte="2">creative</li>
  <li data-sorte="1">euphoric</li>
  <li data-sorte="2">uplifted</li>
  <li data-sorte="1">energetic</li>
  <li data-sorte="0">lazy</li>
  <li data-sorte="1">focused</li>
  <li data-sorte="1">happy</li>
  <li data-sorte="0">talkative</li>
  <li data-sorte="0">giggly</li>
  <li data-sorte="0">tingly</li>
  <li data-sorte="0">hungry</li>
  <li data-sorte="0">sleepy</li>
  <li data-sorte="0">aroused</li>
</ul>
```

I would want it to show `creative`, `uplifted`, `euphoric`, `energetic`, `focused` and `happy` as those are the top options by the numbers. `euphoric`, `energetic`, `focused` and `happy` are all tied at `1` thus I want to show them all. The original script does this.

Comment: loop over each `effects-list` and collect the `li` of that list instance only to sort.

Comment: What do you do with the 4th "2" if there are 4 "2"s ?

Comment: @bloodyKnuckles - It will show the top three numbers and if as you say they are 4 "2"s it will show all four values with 2 in it and nothing else. Make sense?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I slightly modified your script.

```
$('*[data-sorte="0"]').remove();
$(".effects-list").each(function() {
    var $list = $(this),
        $items = $list.find('li'),
        sortes = [];

    $items.detach().sort(sort_li_effects).filter(function(i) {
        var sorte = $(this).data('sorte');
        if (i < 3) {
            sortes.push(sorte);
            return true;
        }

        return sortes.indexOf(sorte) >= 0;
    }).appendTo($list);
});

function sort_li_effects(a, b) {
    return ($(a).data('sorte')) < ($(b).data('sorte')) ? 1 : -1;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/KK2bV/5/ or http://jsfiddle.net/KK2bV/6/ or  http://jsfiddle.net/KK2bV/3/

Major differences:

- It goes through `li` in every `list` and sorts correctly
- It removes all unnecessary items at once using `li:gt(2)`

Comment: I ran into an issue when I tried to implement the script. The problem is my original script would show more than three items IF there were ties in the numbers. In other words `data-sorte` in the li would have values of 2, 2, 1, 1, 1. I would want to show all of those`li` elements because they are the top options even though there is a tie. Does that make sense?

Comment: @Lynda: so what are the criterias then? Why it's not `2 2 1`? Would it change anything if it was `2 2 2`?

Comment: I tried to clarify in my edit to my question. If there was `2 2 2` it would show only those, however, if there is `2 2 1 1 1` it would show all of them. Another example: we have `4 3 2 2 2 1 1 1` I would want `4 3 2 2 2` to show.

Comment: @Lynda: too lazy to think of something elegant, so something that "just works"

Comment: I heard a person say once the best developers are lazy as they like to do things the shortest way possible. Also I don't care about elegance as long as it works and it appears to work when I implement it. Thank You for the help!

Comment: Doesn't work properly if you have something like "4 4 2 2 2 1 1"; it will only show "4 4 2 2 2", which is not a top three.

Comment: @Jack: it does work properly according to the OP explanation. For the `4 4 2 2 2 1 1` the expected result is `4 4 2 2 2`, that is the top 3 records including ties for the least values.

Comment: @zerkms Ahhh, with that being the interpretation you're absolutely right :)

Answer (score 2):

You can do this in the following three steps:

```
$('.effects-list').replaceWith(function() {
  // step 1: grab list of items, remove all zero values and sort descending
  var $items = $(this).children()
    .filter(function() {
      return $(this).data('sorte') !== 0;
    }).sort(function(a, b) {
      var a_value = $(a).data('sorte'),
      b_value = $(b).data('sorte');

      if (a_value != b_value) {
        return a_value > b_value ? -1 : 1;
      }
      return 0;
    }),
  current,
  levels = 0,
  index = 0;

  // step 2: work out the top three
  while (index < $items.length && levels < 3) {
    var value = $items.eq(index).data('sorte');
    if (current === null || current != value) {
      current = value;
      ++levels;
    }
    ++index;
  }

  // step 3: replace the contents      
  return $items.slice(0, index);
});
```

See also: [`.replaceWith()`](http://api.jquery.com/replacewith/#replaceWith-function)

[**Demo**](http://jsbin.com/fiqenika/9/)

Comment: One problem, my original script would show more than three items IF there were ties in the numbers. In other words `data-sorte` in the `li` would have values of 2, 2, 1, 1, 1. I would want to show all of those`li` elements because they are the top options even though there is a tie. Does that make sense?

Comment: Using `$(this).html();` shows all `li` elements vs the top three (including the ties).

Comment: @Lynda I mean `$(this).html(items);`.

Comment: Got it. => It shows all `li` elements with a number.

Answer (score 0):

I don't like jQuery, however I can provide a javascript solution. I can recommend that you structure your HTML so that each UL has an ID that is enumerable. So:

```
 <ul class="effects-list" id="list1"> ... </ul>
 <ul class="...-list" id="list2">...<ul>
```

And so on. Then use a for loop to go through all the lists like this. Assume that there are 10 lists:

```
 for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      var list = document.getElementById("list"+i);
 // Then run your jQuery code on the list 10 times.
 }
```

Does that help?

Comment: I would avoid asking people not to down vote an answer. To me it is okay to post a non-jQuery solution as long as it solves the issue and the OP doesn't specify they are looking for a jQuery only solution.